# Why does PHP create these log entries on every page access?

Tags: php, error, logging

My server's error log (in cPanel) has an entry for every single time a PHP page is loaded that looks like this (where 'username' has been substituted for my actual username):

`[2012-06-09 09:02:07]: info: [usr/grp]: username/username cmd: /home/username/public_html/error.php php: /usr/local/php53/bin/php`

I know it's only an 'info' message but it's filling up my error log. It can't be related to the content of my PHP files because it even happens when I load a page with this as its content:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Any ideas on what it means or if I can get rid of it?

Comment: Are the `auto_prepend_file` and/or `auto_append_file` directives being used to automatically prepend/append PHP file(s) on the request?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To disable ALL error logging from PHP, include this in the top of the PHP files:

```
error_reporting("E_ALL")
```

You can also selectively disable error messages by severity:

```
http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting
```

The `php.ini` file can also be changed rather than putting these inside the actual PHP files, but you mentioned cPanel and I'm not sure if you can edit that.

Comment: `error_reporting` make no difference to error logging, that is a separate option.

Comment: @ionFish: moreover `error_reporting("E_ALL")` would only amplificate the number of errors logged and not reduce them, i.e. `E_NOTICE` is off by default, but if you set `error_reporting("E_ALL")` you are going to turn on also `E_NOTICE` errors.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to disable error logging in PHP. If you cannot modify your php.ini file, you may be able to set the option in your htaccess like this:

```
php_value log_errors 0
```

Alternatively you can use the function `ini_set` in all your PHP files.

The error/info message is a strange one, though. I can't find any information on what it might be. Do all the files/folders listed in the message exist?

Comment: I am reluctant to disable error logging, I'd rather put up with it. I was hoping to find out the cause or turn off that particular one. The error.php file is the page that caused the error and the php directory is listed as 'PHPHANDLER' in PHPInfo, but I can't check if it exists because I don't have access

Comment: You may be able to set error reporting to a level that doesn't include that message, and only shows errors. As for finding the source of the message, if you don't have access to the server then you should contact your host about it.